# Jquery updates div inspite of the content being same

Tags: php, jquery, kdiff3

So I have a page where I allow the user to view contents from a server log. I want the div to be updated only if the content in the server log has changed. If it is the same as what is there in the div, I do not want any updates.

My jquery code looks like this:

```
        $.get("log.php",{log: $('#log').val()}, function(data)
        {
            if((data.trim()) && ($("#logdata").html() != data))
            {
                $("#logdata").html(data);
            }
        });
```

So I am fetching the content and showing it only if there is data and the data is fresh. However I noticed the div gets updated if it is any non-empty data. In other words this condition `(data.trim()` works fine, but `$("#logdata").html() != data)` does not. I am not pasting the log data because there are various logs and the data is fickle, so I do not think it is a data issue.

Furthermore since I am setting the data as `.html()` and comparing it as `.html()` it should not matter.

Also, I took these two contents and compared in Kdiff, but it says **"Files A and B have
equal text, but are not binary equal"**. Does anyone know what it means/how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Please try this:

```
$.get("log.php",{log: $('#log').val()}, function(data)
{
    if((data.trim()) && ($("#logdata").html().toString() != data.toString()))
    {
        $("#logdata").html(data);
    }
});
```